# How to join servers?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

My son wants to join a server on Minecraft (Wii U Edition), but we don't know how.

How can he join a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only join servers of people in your friends list.

You can also play on the splitscreen mode, but it isn't considered a server.

Comment: You mean that when a friend creates a world, we can see it in the "enter" tab, in the "play" option of the main menu. Right?

Comment: And then, if I create a new world on line, my friends can see it and play with me, right?

Answer (score -1):

there are no servers but if you want some PvP just go to mini games>battle>join